# How to add "All my Files" back to Finder sidebar?

Tags: macos, finder, sidebar

The "All my Files" icon in my Finder sidebar has disappeared, I may have inadvertently deleted it with an unlucky motion on the trackpad.

[image]

[This helpful answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139306/143729) shows the following technique, but I have no "All my Files" folder to grab

[image]

[This helpful answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/329307/143729) suggests I could do it in Python, but I'm a little nervous about trying it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from FinderSidebarEditor import FinderSidebar                  # Import the module

sidebar = FinderSidebar()                                      # Create a Finder sidebar instance to act on.

sidebar.add("All My Files")     # EDIT: I'm guessing this will work
```

I found [this tutorial](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25527?viewlocale=en_US) but nothing about "All my Files" that I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, found it!

MacWorld's May 2017 Mac 911 article [How to show the All My Files icon in the macOS Sidebar](https://www.macworld.com/article/3197433/how-to-show-the-all-my-files-icon-in-the-macos-sidebar.html) points out that there is a menu in preferences:

[image] [image]

click `All My Files` and it's back:

[image]

Comment: All my Files does not show up on my iMac running High Sierra, That location now has "Recent" there.

Comment: @jmh, It's actually "Recents".